# "Algunos idiomas tienen errores" App Store subida app

Tags: android, app, google-play

¡Hola a todos!

Estoy intentando subir una app a la Play Store (es la primera vez) y al intentar agregar un idioma me salta el error "Algunos idiomas tienen errores". Incluso el idioma predeterminado falla.

La app está en español, la configuración de Google también y no encuentro información sobre qué puede ocurrir.

¿A alguien más le ha pasado o alguien sabe qué puede ser?

¡Muchas gracias!   [image: PROBLEMA APP STORE]

Comment: Revisa los campos obligatorios, tuve un caso similar donde el mensaje se quito hasta cargar el grafico de funciones.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema indica que alguno de los datos requeridos o mandatorios son incorrectos o faltan.

Estas son algunas causas:

- No se definio titulo.
- No se definen urls https://
- No se agrego descripcion corta y larga.
- Imagenes o iconos no reunen especificaciones.

Si tienes definido mas de un idioma seleccionalo y podras ver que alguna de las caracteristicas requeridas puede tener algun problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

El mensaje en mi caso fue engañoso.Lo que me pasaba es que al seleccionar varios del mismo idioma pero diferentes versiones:

-Español
-Español latinoamerica...etc

Te obliga a rellenar la ficha individualmente para cada uno aunque sean todos Español(por ejemplo). Hay que seleccionarlos y rellenar cada ficha.